# Sorting data using jQgrid locally

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I use jQgrid for loading data once from server utilizing an webservice in xml format and after that use the sorting capability of jqgrid.
At first data are loaded correctly, but when I use sorting the data in each row are scrambled which means incorrect data in each row.
sorting is done, but for every column,the data from another row is placed in each row.
here is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.svc/getInfoXML",
        dataType: "json",
        data: vdata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (json) {
            var data = json.d;
            jQuery("#tblDevs").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'xmlstring',


                datastr: data,

                colNames: [x1, x2, x3,x4],
                colModel: [
                                { name: 'devSerial', index: 'devSerial', hidden: true, width: 20, sortable: false },
                                { name: 'devName', index: 'devName', width: 100, sorttype: "string" },
                                { name: 'groupName', index: 'devSerial', hidden: true, width: 20, sortable: false },
                                { name: 'speed', index: 'speed', width: 70, sorttype: "number" },
                                { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 115, sorttype: "string" },
                         ],
                viewrecords: true,
                direction: gridDirection,
                multiselect: false,
                rowNum: -1,
                rowTotal: 100000,
                width: 740,
                loadonce: true,
                sortable: true,
                gridComplete: function (rowId, rowData, rowElem) {


                    var grid = $("#tblDevs");
                    var rowData = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                    try {
                        for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
                            var emsStatus = jQuery("#tblDevs").getCell(rowData[i], "statusCode");
                            changeDevTableColor(emsStatus, rowData[i]);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (err) {

                    }
                },
                scrollrows: true,
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    var serial = jQuery("#tblDevs").getCell(id, "devSerial");
                    locate(serial);
                }


            });

function changeDevTableColor(emsStatus, rowId) {
    if (emsStatus == 6) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle6');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 7) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle7');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 8) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle8');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 9) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle9');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 10) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle10');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 11) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle11');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 12) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle12');
    }
    else if (emsStatus == 13) {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle13');
    }
    else {
        $("#tblDevs").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, false, 'missionStyle14');
    }
}
```

sample output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<invoices>
    <rows>

        <row>
            <cell>63101</cell>
            <cell>3713</cell>
            <cell>-----</cell>
            <cell>1.26</cell>
            <cell>1394/12/12 21:44:57</cell>
            <cell>جنوب شرقی</cell>
            <cell>38</cell>
            <cell>309070</cell>
            <cell>140542</cell>
            <cell>حرکت از محل حادثه</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>63100</cell>
            <cell>3723</cell>
            <cell>-----</cell>
            <cell>0.17</cell>
            <cell>1395/01/31 13:21:55</cell>
            <cell>جنوب شرقی</cell>
            <cell>22</cell>
            <cell>76343</cell>
            <cell>143153</cell>
            <cell>حالت نامشخص</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>60814</cell>
            <cell>3724</cell>
            <cell>-----</cell>
            <cell>68.39</cell>
            <cell>1394/12/07 16:37:00</cell>
            <cell>شمال شرقی</cell>
            <cell>99</cell>
            <cell>221504</cell>
            <cell>139486</cell>
            <cell>رسیدن به بیمارستان</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>63102</cell>
            <cell>3733</cell>
            <cell>-----</cell>
            <cell>7</cell>
            <cell>1395/02/04 15:15:47</cell>
            <cell>شمال</cell>
            <cell>98</cell>
            <cell>246200</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
            <cell>حالت نامشخص</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>60975</cell>
            <cell>60975</cell>
            <cell>-----</cell>
            <cell>0.2</cell>
            <cell>1394/03/19 12:59:03</cell>
            <cell>شرق</cell>
            <cell>99</cell>
            <cell>14440</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
            <cell>حالت نامشخص</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>63336</cell>
            <cell>63336</cell>
            <cell>-----</cell>
            <cell>0.02</cell>
            <cell>1394/03/19 10:39:59</cell>
            <cell>شمال غربی</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
            <cell>حالت نامشخص</cell>
        </row>

    </rows>
</invoices>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide test data? Why you use `index: 'devSerial'` for **both** columns `devSerial` and `groupName`? One should typically *remove* all `index` properties. Could you include the code of `changeDevTableColor`? I suppose that you want to set the color or background color of cone cells or some rows of the grid depend on the value from `statusCode` column. The usage of `cellattr` or `rowattr` is the correct way to do this. The usage of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and the method `getLocalRow` is strictly recommended too.

Comment: test data is so simple just rows of string and number I just omit it for simplicity. About hidden fields I don't have any idea because this code is borrowed from another coder I could not understand the meaning, but about changeDevTableColor you are right. @Oleg

Comment: the basic question here is do I use jqgrid options in the right approach or jqgrid do not has any bug about sorting locally ?

Comment: Sorry, but if you want that I help you, then you should answer on my questions too. I repeat there: **Could you provide test data? Could you include the code of `changeDevTableColor`?** It's important to know the data to understand the reason of the problem. What you do in the code is very strange. You make a call to WCF service `url: "WebService.svc/getInfoXML"``using `dataType: "json"` (!!! not `dataType: "xml"`), then you get `d` property `json.d` and to use the data as `datatype: 'xmlstring'`. It's really suspected! One use typically either JSON or XML, but not a strange mix of both.

Comment: I add the function, yes you are right I check the service, it creates xml but I don't know why use json as returned datatype, anyway the service returns a string
I mention the requested function and sample output of the service in the question. thanks @Oleg

Comment: OK, now I probably see the problem. First of all `gridComplete` can be replaced to small `rowattr` function which set additional classes of the row (`<tr>`) depend on input data. Another question: you use `jQuery("#tblDevs").getCell(rowData[i], "statusCode")` to get data from `statusCode` column, but you have no column with such name? Which version of jqGrid you use? It's very important. If specific version of jqGrid is not important for you then I'd recommend you to use the latest free jqGrid (4.13.2). The next question: why you return **XML** data instead of JSON data?

Comment: One should return **object** (`List<MyItem>` or `List<dynamic>`) from WCF method (WebService.svc). Then you will work only with *native* objects in C# code and the object will be converted to JSON or XML *by .NET framework* depend on `dataType: "json"` or `dataType: "xml"` which you use in Ajax request. Could you include fragment of WCF code which you use? I could explain that on the example. Web.config would be interesting too (system.serviceModel part especially).

Comment: all of the rows has statusCode $nbsp; :| so all of the rows are as the same color, coloumn statusCode is existed but not filled at the server side.
the version of jqgrid is V4-4-1, you know it is hard to migrate to last version because of some compatibility issues.
as I mentioned before this code is borrowed from another person so I really haven't any idea about outputing the result of service as XML.
The order of grid rows is changing sequentially as a result data is scrambled ! @Oleg

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem which you describe neither with jqGrid 4.4.1 (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Resa-4-4-1.htm)) nor with the latest free jqGrid from GitHub (see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Resa.htm)). By the way I replaced the code, which you use to set class depend on the value from `statusCode` column (non-existing column in the grid) with the `rowattr` callabck

```
rowattr: function (item) {
    var className;
    if (6 <= item.statusCode && item.statusCode <= 13) {
        className = "missionStyle" + item.statusCode;
    } else {
        className = "missionStyle14";
    }
    return { "class": className };
}
```

and added `gridview: true` option for old jqGrid to improve the performance. In any way I can't reproduce any problem with sorting of data.

Comment: thanks about your advice about     rowattr     and gridview option. It seems the problem is related to another bunch of code. And the jqgrid is working fine anyway. This omits one of my hypothesis about resolving the problem. thanks @Oleg